# Expression.IfThenElse error (C#)

Tags: c#, linq, expression, xna-4.0

I have such error:

> Error 1   'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression' does not contain a
>   definition for 'IfThenElse'

How to ommit it?

Here's code (The AluminiumLua library for C#):

```
public virtual void IfThenElse()
    {
        var Else = Expression.Call(stack.Pop(), LuaObject_AsFunction);
        var Then = Expression.Call(stack.Pop(), LuaObject_AsFunction);
        var Cond = Expression.Call(stack.Pop(), LuaObject_AsBool);
        stack.Push(Expression.IfThenElse(
            Cond,
            Expression.Call(Then, LuaFunction_Invoke, Expression.NewArrayInit(typeof(LuaObject), new Expression[] { })),
            Expression.Call(Else, LuaFunction_Invoke, Expression.NewArrayInit(typeof(LuaObject), new Expression[] { }))
        ));
    }
```

Comment: I doubt you'd be able to get any help without posting the offending code.

Comment: You'll have to include the code that causes the error.

Comment: Are you using .NET 4 (~ Visual Studio 2010) ?

Comment: VS 2012 Express for Windows Phone 8.0. Project C# + XNA 4.0

Answer (score 0):

[`Expression.IfThenElse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.ifthenelse.aspx) was introduced in .NET Framework 4, **later** than the `Expression` library (which was 3.5). So if you're working with some `Expression` code that requires 4.0, and you're using 3.5, it's possible that *most* of it will compile, but not `IfThenElse`.

I note that [the most recent commit to AluminiumLua](https://github.com/chkn/AluminumLua/commit/41f1a73cffbc13e070b1cc99b7095c2428fc289f) has as its commment

> Now we require .NET 4.0

so if you are using the latest code you will need to follow this instruction.

I'm afraid I'm not really up to speed on what framework pieces are or aren't available in WP8 and/or XNA, but hopefully this will provide some useful clues.

Comment: It's ok now, I've changed 'IfThenElse' for 'Condition', It compiles.

Answer (score -1):

I think you made a mistake. I think it is IfElse

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30570924)